# UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete color to green

Tags: ios, uitableview

When I slide my finger from left to right in a row, I want that `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath` method returns the same `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` button but with green color.

Is it possible? How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to create your button. You can use a `UIButton` and set the background images to your graphics. Then, set the `editingAccessoryView` property of the cell to your button. You do this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

If you need more flexibility you can create your own UIButton and/or UITableViewCell subclass.